# Maximum depth update exceeded error when navigating to routes react-router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I am using react-router v6 I am trying to protect some routes and not give access to users if they are not authenticated. I am using the token to determine if user is authenticated or not. After I login into the app using login details instead of returning **todos** route it doesn't show anything. I get this error message on the console **Maximum depth update exceeded**. However, if I'm not protecting the routes it works fine.

This is how I am protecting routes.

```
const token = useSelector(state => state.authDetails.token );

  let routes = (
    <Routes>
      
      <Route path='/signUp' exact  element={<SignUpForm />}/>
      <Route path='/'  exact element={<LoginForm />}/>
      <Route path='*' replace element={<Navigate to="/" />}/>
    </Routes>
  )

  if(token !== null ) {
    routes = (
      <Routes>

        <Route path='/todos' element={<AddTodo/>}/>
        <Route path='/logout' element={<Logout/>}/>
        <Route path='*' replace element={<Navigate to="/" />}/>
      </Routes>
    )
  }

 return (
    <div className="App">
      <header>
         <Navbar />
      </header>
        
         {routes}

        
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

When `token !== null` you are returning a set of routes that includes a redirect to `"/"` but doesn't include a route rendering a path for `"/"`, so the app is caught in a render loop redirecting to a non-existent route.

## Solution

Include a route with `path="/"` in your "authenticated" path, or redirect to a route that is being rendered, like `"/todos":

```
const token = useSelector(state => state.authDetails.token);

let routes = (
  <Routes>
    <Route path='/signUp' exact  element={<SignUpForm />} />
    <Route path='/'  exact element={<LoginForm />} />
    <Route path='*' element={<Navigate to="/" replace />} />
  </Routes>
);

if (token !== null) {
  routes = (
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/todos' element={<AddTodo/>} />
      <Route path='/logout' element={<Logout/>} />
      <Route path='*' element={<Navigate to="/todos" replace />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

return (
  <div className="App">
    <header>
      <Navbar />
    </header>
    {routes}
  </div>
);
```

An improved solution would be to create an authenticated wrapper component and wrap the routes you want to protect.

Example:

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const AuthWrapper = () => {
  const token = useSelector(state => state.authDetails.token);

  return token !== null ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/" replace />;
};
```

...

```
return (
  <div className="App">
    <header>
      <Navbar />
    </header>
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/signUp' element={<SignUpForm />} />
      <Route path='/' element={<LoginForm />} />
      <Route element={<AuthWrapper />}>
        <Route path='/todos' element={<AddTodo />} />
        <Route path='/logout' element={<Logout />} />
      </Route>
      <Route path='*' element={<Navigate to="/" replace />} />
    </Routes>
  </div>
);
```

### Update

If you need to conditionally redirect to different targets on the wildcard route then create another wrapper to handle the auth check.

Example:

```
const RedirectWrapper = () => {
  const token = useSelector(state => state.authDetails.token);

  return <Navigate to={token !== null ? "/todos" : "/" replace />;
};
```

...

```
return (
  <div className="App">
    <header>
      <Navbar />
    </header>
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/signUp' element={<SignUpForm />} />
      <Route path='/' element={<LoginForm />} />
      <Route element={<AuthWrapper />}>
        <Route path='/todos' element={<AddTodo />} />
        <Route path='/logout' element={<Logout />} />
      </Route>
      <Route path='*' element={<RedirectWrapper />} />
    </Routes>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Thanks, the first solution worked when included `"/todos" route in authenticated routes for any redirect routes but the second solution redirects to a non existent route.

Comment: @coder What is the non-existent route that is being redirected to?

Comment: I'm redirected to login route instead of todos route.

Comment: @coder Both a `path="/"` and `path="/todos"` route exists for being redirected to in my answer. Should the wildcard route redirect to `"/todos"` instead of the login `"/"` path?

Comment: The wildcard  route should redirect to '/todos'  instead of  '/' when the user is logged in.

Comment: @coder I see. I have updated my answer to add a section for handling conditional redirects for unhandled paths.

Comment: we still have the same issue. we are redirected to login '/' instead of '/todos'

Comment: @coder I suppose that means `token` is null because if it's anything *other than* null it will redirect to `"/todos"` in the `RedirectWrapper` component. Is null the initial `state.authDetails.token` state value and is your app checking/updating this state on a subsequent render cycle?

Comment: Token is not null because I console.log the token.